# Session Variables Are not Defined with AJAX - Node.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session-variables

### The Problem:

Hello, i am trying to call a php file from node.js with AJAX, but when i do, the session variables return undefined and the database doesn't update. However, the php file does work because i tested it with a link in the browser. Unfortunately, i can not just define the session variables as data for AJAX because i can not include php in javascript or html. (Node JS doesn't allow me to change my index.html to index.php).

---

### What Works:

- **The File:** When i place the php file as a link in the browser, the database is correctly updated and everything works perfectly.
- **AJAX:** When i call the php file from AJAX, it does echo the success message but when i changed the success message to one of the session variables, it returns blank. (This is how i found out that the variables are the problem)

---

### The Code:

***PHP:***

**subtract5.php**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://cashballz.net:3000', false);
include 'mysql.php'; 
session_start(); 

$cash_amount = $_SESSION['cash_amount'];
$userid = $_SESSION['id'];
$_SESSION['cash_amount'] -= 0.05;

$mysql = new Mysql(); 

$result = $mysql->setCashAmount($cash_amount,$userid); 
if($result) 
{ 
echo "5 cents have been subtracted!"; 
} 
else 
{ 
session_start(); 
session_unset(); 
session_destroy(); 
}
?>
```

**mysql.php**

```
<?php
class Mysql 
{ 
protected $dsn; 
protected $username; 
protected $password; 
public $db; 


function __construct() 
{ 

$this->dns= 'mysql:dbname=cashball_accounts;host=localhost;charset=utf8'; 
$this->username= 'myUser'; 
$this->password= 'myPass'; 
$this->db = new PDO($this->dns, $this->username, $this->password); 
} 


public function setCashAmount($cash_amount, $id) 
{ 
$sql = "UPDATE users SET cash_amount = :cash_amount - 0.05 WHERE id = :id"; 
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bindParam(':cash_amount', $cash_amount, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$result = $stmt->execute(); 
return $result; 
} 

} 
?>
```

***JS:***

**app.js**

```
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://cashballz.net/game/5game/subtract5.php',
    data: {}, 
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

---

### Conclusion:

I was thinking that when i deploy the node server from index.php (my website's index file - not node's which is index.html) then i could send the php variables to like a json file with a global database and access that from node, but i tried to research it and have no idea how that works.

I am a beginner to PHP so i am open to many different solutions!

P.S. The most secure solution is preferred because my website uses real money.

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: I am confused, are you trying to make an ajax call from a client where node.js produced the html or are you trying to establish communication between backend node.js and a server which inteprets php codes. This part `when i deploy the node server from index.php` confuses even more

Comment: "when i deploy the node server from index.php" means when i press the button to take me to the port (mywebsite.com:3000)

Comment: Does the URL for the original page begin with `http://cashballz.net`?

Comment: yes it does, the original page is that link and then the port to get to the node server is 3000